# Why can i not get records has an array field contains primary key value in dynamoosejs?

Tags: node.js, dynamoose, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to the dynamodb. I'm encountering an irritating problem
I have a record stored in the dynamodb like this:

```
{
 bmgIds: ["d5a03ea2-e06e-5d01-84b7-94530b1059f7"],
 id: "d5a03ea2-e06e-5d01-84b7-94530b1059f7",
 .....
}
```

as you see, **bmgIds** array contains **id** value, when i used **scan** operation to get records has **bmgIds** match my condition but cannot get that record with my code

```
Model.scan('bmgIds').contains("d5a03ea2-e06e-5d01-84b7-94530b1059f7").exec()
```

I noticed that I can get records has bmgIds field not contains **id** value with code above

please help to explain where I'm wrong!

sorry I'm bad in English, I wish to receive help from you, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to AWS scan response limit